# Get a sub-directory folder in the URL and echo it .

Tags: php

How do I get the value of an URL eg. `www.example.php/folders/crowd`? I'm trying to echo out crowd with PHP. I have tried using the `$_SERVER ['SCRIPTNAME']` but I really cant get it to work.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the current directory of the file (which is just "crowd" in your "www.example.php/folders/crowd" example), use:

`$cur_dir = basename(dirname($_SERVER[PHP_SELF]))`

If you just want the file, then try this:

`$cur_file = $_SERVER[PHP_SELF];`

Comment: Then `echo $_SERVER[PHP_SELF];` should work fine. From http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php: "'PHP_SELF' - The filename of the currently executing script."

Answer (score 3):

You can use parse_url, because scriptname will return the real php file execution "index.php" for example.

```
php > var_dump(parse_url('http://www.example.php/folders/crowd', PHP_URL_PATH));
// "/folders/crowd"
```

But if you want just the last part you can:

```
$tmp = explode('/', 'www.example.php/folders/crowd');
var_dump(end($tmp));
// "crowd"
```

Or another way:

```
var_dump(basename(parse_url('http://www.example.php/folders/crowd', PHP_URL_PATH)));
// "crowd"
```

Comment: Try this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/77366628/5591121

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to have a look at the Apache module **[mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html)**. Many web hosting provider offer this module. If you even operate a dedicated server owned by you, it's no problem to install / enable this module.

**mod_rewrite** can be used to transparently "transform" request URLs to requests for defined php scripts with query string parameters derived from the original request. This is often used for SEO-friendly URLs like `http://mywebpage/article/how-to-cook-pizza-123.html`. In this case a script might be invoked taking only the `123` from the URL as a parameter (e.g. `http://mywebpage/article/how-to-cook-pizza-123.html` => `/article.php?id=123`).

In your case you could use a configuration like this (put this into an [.htaccess file](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html) or your Apache/vhost configuration):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^folders/[A-Za-z]+$ showfolder.php?user=$1 [L]
```

Your `showfolder.php` might look like this:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['user'])) {
        echo htmlentities($_GET['user']);
    } else {
        echo "No parameter found.";
    }
?>
```

Any word after `folders/` that consists of letters (A-Z and a-z) will be taken as the `user` parameter of your php script. Then you can easily `echo` this value, fetch it from a database or whatever. For example, a request for `/folders/crowd` will result in your script being executed with this parameter: `showfolder.php?user=crowd`. The user of your website won't see anything of this hidden internal forwarding.

If you use some other web server software ([nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpRewriteModule), ...): There are [similar modules for other web server products](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpRewriteModule), too.