# Get wordpress subdirectory

Tags: wordpress

When my wordpress is installed on `site.com/subfolder` I need a way to get `/subfolder` with a wordpress function. I know how to get the whole URL and how to get the whole directory, but I simply need the subfolder.

For `site.com/subfolder/subfolder` I would of course need `/subfolder/subsubfolder`

**Edit:**
My question is different from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20133436) because the user only wants the last folder (e.g `subsubfolder`), but I want all folders (e.g. `/subfolder/subsubfolder`)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get a sub-directory folder in the URL and echo it .](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20133436/get-a-sub-directory-folder-in-the-url-and-echo-it)

Comment: <?php echo site_url() . '/wp-content/themes/themename/subfolder'; ?>

Comment: @YahyaHussein Nope he only wants the *last* folder, I want all folders

Comment: @SunilDora Nope that gives me the complete url, I only want the folder part...

Comment: check the latest answer

Comment: But I don't want to use mod_rewrite or htaccess, I want a php or wordpress function

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20133500/5077196 this answer

Comment: Ok, that would fit, but when the user accesses a subpage (not subfolder) the script will return also the subpage: `/subfolder/subsubfolder/subpage`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `site_url( '', 'relative');`